# Launch javascript code in a browser

Tags: javascript, c#, outlook, add-in

I am doing an add-in for Outlook (C#) I created a button in the Ribbon. When I click on the button I want to automatically open a browser with url and then launch a javascript `javascript:Goto();` in the code behind. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the javascript is just a part of the page opened, yes, that is possible. You can open the URL with [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s(v=vs.110).aspx). It will open the default browser (so from there you have little control over the execution):

```
Process.Start(@"http://somewebsite.sample");
```

Another option is the use of the [`WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) control in c#. You can execute custom javascript in it too. You can use [`WebBrowser.InvokeScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc452443(v=vs.110).aspx) for that. You need to place that on a `Form` inside your application.

```
this.webBrowser.Navigate("http://somewebsite.sample")
this.webBrowser.InvokeScript("SomeGotoMethod", new object[] { "somevariable" });
```

Comment: I try this :Form webFrom = new Form();
            WebBrowser webPage = new WebBrowser();
            webPage.Navigate("www.google.be");
            webFrom.Show(); and I have a empty Form

Comment: Where did you add that control? `webFrom.Controls.Add(webPage);`

Comment: I forget webFrom.Controls.Add(webPage); Thank's. Now I am going to try to invoke script

Comment: I want to use `webBrowser.InvokeScript();` I have an error `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser does not contain a definition for InvokeScript and no extension method InvokeScript accepting a first argument of type System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: What arguments did you pass in?

Comment: javascript:Goto('DM_NEW_OBJECT.ASPX?DM_CAT_ID=2171&amp;DM_PARENT_ID=254769&amp;INPUTSELECTION=&amp;DM_OBJECT_ID=0&amp;PACK_ID=0&amp;CASE_ID=0&amp;mode=0&amp;SITE=Default');

Comment: Try: `InvokeScript("Goto", "DM_NEW_OBJECT.ASPX...")`

Comment: I think is `webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript` and not `webBrowser.InvokeScript`

Comment: No, it isn't. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc452443(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: I saw but when i try this i have error : `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser does not contain a definition for InvokeScript` I have only `Invoke` on autocompletion

Comment: @mosflex: My bad. See the updated answer (last line of code).

Comment: It's the same. The problem is not the arguments but the call of method he doesn't exist for WebBrowser I don't know why !

Comment: It does not recognize `InvokeScript` I have only `Invoke`